# Explicitly changing the name of a column with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How can you rename a field name in a table which generates Hibernate?
When you create:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = GroupRightEntity.class)
or
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = UserRightEntity.class)
```

Now made with an explicit change of names of columns in the Database.

```
alter table security_mapping_user rename column sec_mapping_id to secmappingentity_id;
```

Thank you for your help and understanding.

---

Hibernate generates links for additional tables. Accordingly, I understand that the generated field names. I need to use annotations, or something else, these column names change. I hope I wrote everything correctly.

---

We have.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class RoleEntity implements Role, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_ROLE")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ROLE", sequenceName="SEQ_ROLE", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

@Entity
@Table(name = "URL")
public class UrlEntity implements Url, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_URL")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_URL", sequenceName="SEQ_URL", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    private String url;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = RoleEntity.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="url_id")
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

Later we get a third table. "URL_ROLE"

In this table, the fields are named.
"URL_ID" and "ROLE_ID"

"URL_ID" need to rename the field in the "urlentity_id".

It seems now I built everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a ManyToMany you should also define which column your relationship maps on. That's where you should change the name.

Comment: Annotations @Column not see it does not. You give an example?
But it is understood that it is necessary to change the name of a column in the table that Hibernate generates automatically.